# firebase realtime storage getting a specific value from all children

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am building a app using firebase that requires an admin page and in it i want to make a list of all the usernames of users registered in the system and i am using this code:

```
    Usernames = new ArrayList<>();
    usersdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    usersdb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot user:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Usernames.add(user.child("username").getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Usernames);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
```

and for some reason nothing shows up in the list view in the end anyone knows why?

and my data structure looks like this:(the random letters are user uids)

```
Users
----sdfbsif
-----------email
-----------username
-----------password
----djgsvnv
-----------email
-----------username
-----------password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling setAdapter() before the data is available from your listener.  `addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately, which means you're passing an empty list to the adapter.  Put log messages throughout your code to see the order in which it's executing.

Instead, you could call setAdapter in the callback after all the data from the snapshot is available.

Comment: Alternatively you can "pre-attach" the adapter (what you're doing now) and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` when the data has loaded in  `onDataChange()`.

Comment: umm maybe but ive noticed that ever since i added a edit text to the page the second i click on the edit text the listview shows all users any idea why?

Comment: Maybe a change in layout forces a refresh of the ListView's adapter.  I wouldn't depend on side effects like that.